# Platform runtime and dependencies

Tags: tycho, eclipse-pde

Target Platform understanding required and dependencies in eclipse plugin development.
I am pulling my hair out for the past 3 days.

If I specify the following:-

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eclipse-helios</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
```

1)To me I am making sure my plugin is compatible to run from helios on wards, am I wrong in my thinking?
2)Should that not have resolved my the platform dependencies?

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: plugin1 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: plugin1 1.0.0.qualifier requires 
'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.core.runtime 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] See 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for 
help
```

my manifest file contains:-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Plugin1
Bundle-SymbolicName: plugin1;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: xxx
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.ui
Automatic-Module-Name: plugin1
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

3)[image]

When I run my plugin it works under helious.
Please help me using tycho and maven to achieve this. I just don't understand 'eclipse speak' in its help text.

Someone help me please please
Regards,
Jemrug

Comment: I'm on eclipse: Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200. My colleague is on Kepler and it works for them when I send my projects to them.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I tried in another eclipse workspace and it is all good. So it was a workspace issue.
My only question is how do I do this in standalone mvn as I keep getting the :

```
    mvn clean install

    Cannot resolve project dependencies:
    [ERROR]   Software being installed: plugin1 1.0.0.qualifier
    [ERROR]   Missing requirement: plugin1 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'osgi.bundle; 
    org.eclipse.core.runtime 0.0.0'
```

So why is all well inside eclipse but not command line I get the above.